# Excel Interop Rotate 3d Pie Chart

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Does anyone knows how change the default angle rotation on y axis?
i have tried with chartObj.Chart.Rotation, but it doesnt change anything?
The type of chart that i`m using is 3dPieExploded.

Thanks, 
Florin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `Chart.Elevation` parameter. Use a value between -90 and 90 degree.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy :)